# NSLayoutConstraints not cooperating with UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

In my `UIView` subclass, I have one image view and three labels:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
let firstLabel = UILabel()
let secondLabel = UILabel()
let thirdLabel = UILabel()
```

The image and texts are set by the view controller that uses the view.

I begin to set them up with:

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
addSubview(imageView)

firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
firstLabel.textAlignment = .center
addSubview(firstLabel)

secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
secondLabel.textAlignment = .center
addSubview(secondLabel)

thirdLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
thirdLabel.textAlignment = .center
addSubview(thirdLabel)
```

I am trying to constrain these in such a way such that it looks like the following (rough drawing):

[image]

Specifically:

1. `thirdLabel` is in the center at the bottom
2. `secondLabel` is in the center directly above `thirdLabel`
3. `firstLabel` is in the center directly above `secondLabel`
4. The size of `imageView` will vary depending on the size of the view, however it must meet these criteria:

   - It is in the center directly above `firstLabel`
   - It reaches the top
   - It is a square

So if the height of the view was larger, only the image view would enlarge, the labels would NOT increase height and evenly space out. They would remain at the bottom. So visually, this would be good:

[image]

and this would be bad:

[image]

An example of what I've tried (one of MANY):

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    thirdLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
    thirdLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    thirdLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    thirdLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            
    secondLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.centerXAnchor),
    secondLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.topAnchor),
    secondLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.leadingAnchor),
    secondLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.trailingAnchor),
            
    firstLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.centerXAnchor),
    firstLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.topAnchor),
    firstLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.leadingAnchor),
    firstLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.trailingAnchor),
            
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLabel.centerXAnchor),
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLabel.topAnchor),
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor),
])
```

I've mixed and matched so many constraints but I cannot achieve the layout in the first image. Not only can I get it working with various heights, I can't even get it to work with ANY height. Sometimes the image view takes up the whole thing and I can't even see the labels (are they underneath the view? behind the image view?). Sometimes the height of the labels are increased. These things occur even though I have constraints that seemingly don't allow this to happen? No breaking of constraint messages appear in the console either.

I believe it may have something to do with sizing, because if I don't set an image (and set a background color for `imageView` so I can see where it is), it works perfectly. It's only when I actually assign an image to `imageView.image` do things act up. I've tried resizing the image beforehand, along with setting many variables and constraints not shown in the particular example given above.

Frustrating!

Comment: According to your requirements, when the width of the superview is small, the image might go out of bounds of the superview. Is that okay? If not, please specify more requirements

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both `Content Compression Resistance` and `Content Hugging` priorities on your labels.

Here is an example custom view class (using mostly your code):

```
class AJPView: UIView {
    
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let firstLabel = UILabel()
    let secondLabel = UILabel()
    let thirdLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        addSubview(imageView)
        
        firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        firstLabel.textAlignment = .center
        addSubview(firstLabel)
        
        secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        secondLabel.textAlignment = .center
        addSubview(secondLabel)
        
        thirdLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        thirdLabel.textAlignment = .center
        addSubview(thirdLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            thirdLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            thirdLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            thirdLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            
            secondLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.topAnchor),
            secondLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.leadingAnchor),
            secondLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.trailingAnchor),
            
            firstLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.topAnchor),
            firstLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.leadingAnchor),
            firstLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.trailingAnchor),
            
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLabel.centerXAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLabel.topAnchor),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor),

            // you've given the labels leading and trailing constraints,
            //  so you don't need these
            //thirdLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
            //secondLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.centerXAnchor),
            //firstLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.centerXAnchor),

        ])
    
        // prevent labels from being compressed or stretched vertically
        [firstLabel, secondLabel, thirdLabel].forEach {
            $0.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            $0.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        }
        
        // let's give the subviews background colors
        //  so we can easily see the frames
        let clrs: [UIColor] = [
            .systemYellow,
            .green,
            .cyan,
            .yellow
        ]
        
        for (v, c) in zip([imageView, firstLabel, secondLabel, thirdLabel], clrs) {
            v.backgroundColor = c
        }
        
    }

}
```

and a demo view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let testView = AJPView()
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        heightConstraint = testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),

            // activate height anchor
            heightConstraint,
            
        ])
        
        testView.firstLabel.text = "First"
        testView.secondLabel.text = "Second"
        testView.thirdLabel.text = "Third"

        if let img = UIImage(named: "myImage") {
            testView.imageView.image = img
        } else {
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle.fill") {
                testView.imageView.image = img
            }
        }

        // so we can see the frame of the view
        testView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        testView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        // add grow / shrink buttons
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.spacing = 20
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        ["Taller", "Shorter"].forEach {
            let b = UIButton(type: .system)
            b.backgroundColor = .yellow
            b.setTitle($0, for: [])
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            stack.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }
        view.addSubview(stack)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
        ])
        
    }
    
    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        var h = heightConstraint.constant
        if sender.currentTitle == "Taller" {
            h += 10
        } else {
            h -= 10
        }
        heightConstraint.constant = h
    }
    
}
```

The output looks like this (the custom view is outlined in red):

[image]

you can tap the "Taller" / "Shorter" buttons to make the custom view grow or shrink (by 10-pts each tap) to see the changes:

[image]

Note that the view will eventually get too tall for the `1:1` ratio image view to fit horizontally:

[image]